# How to version docker images with build number in Jenkins to deploy as Kubernetes deployment?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Currently I am trying to add version number or build number for Docker image to deploy on Kubernetes cluster. Previously I was working only with `:latest` tag. But when I am using `latest` tag , I found problem for pulling from Dockerhub image registry. So when I am using the build number to my docker image like `<image-name>:{build-number}` .

### Application Structure

In my Kubernetes deployment, I am using deployment and service. I am defining my image repository in my deployment file like the following,

```
   containers:
   - name: test-kube-deployment-container
     image: samplekubernetes020/testimage:latest
     ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 8085
          protocol: TCP
```

Here instead of latest tag, I want to put build number with my image in deployment YAML.

1. Can I use an environment variable for holding the random build number for accessing like `<image-name>:${buildnumber}` ?
2. If i want to use a environment variable which providing the random number how I can generate a random number to a environment variable?

**Updates On Image Version Implementation**

My modified Jenkinsfile contains the step like following to assign the image version number to image. But still I am not getting the updated result after changes to repository,

I created step like the following in Jenkinsfile

```
stage ('imagebuild')
  {
     steps
         {
 sh 'docker build -f /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/jpipeline/pipeline/Dockerfile -t spacestudymilletech010/spacestudykubernetes /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/jpipeline/pipeline'
 sh 'docker login --username=my-username --password=my-password' 
 sh "docker tag spacestudymilletech010/spacestudykubernetes:latest spacestudymilletech010/spacestudykubernetes:${VERSION}"
 sh 'docker push spacestudymilletech010/spacestudykubernetes:latest'

         }
  }
```

And my deployment YAML file contains like the following,

```
 containers:
   - name: test-kube-deployment-container
     image: spacestudymilletech010/spacestudykubernetes:latest
     ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 8085
          protocol: TCP
```

**Confusions**

**NB:** When I am checking the dockerhub repository, every time it showing the latest push status

So my confusions are:

1. Is there any problem with pulling latest image in my deployment.yaml file?
2. Is the problem when I am tagging the image at my machine from where I am building the image and pushing?

Comment: you can do this via CI/CD pipeline easily. Try with tools like CircleCI, Azure devops

Comment: @TusharMahajan - I am using CI/CD pipeline. When I am defining my kubernetes resource instead of using latest tag , I need to use image build number/version for pulling from dockerhub.com. Because already there is image pulling issue with latest tag.

Comment: Tools like [Helm](https://helm.sh) and [Kustomize](https://kustomize.io/) can inject the build number (in very different ways).  The sequential build number from your CI system our your source control commit ID both make perfectly good image tags and they don't need to be random _per se_.

Comment: @DavidMaze - Yes , I already tried with Kubernetes Helm chart.Successfully deploying using Helm chart. But Now I am working with plane kubernetes resource deployment R&D. Here I need to check feasibility of deployment without helm chart.Only by using deployment , services. Because I am checking with how random number can generate and assign in my image build. I hope that you understood what I am trying to explore ? please let me know sir.

Comment: Plain `kubectl apply` doesn't have any substitution capabilities.

Comment: @DavidMaze - OK Is there any way to give time stamp for building image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard way or at least the way that has worked for most of us is to create versioned or tagged images. For example

```
samplekubernetes020/testimage:1
samplekubernetes020/testimage:2
samplekubernetes020/testimage:3
...
...
```

Now I will try to answer your actual question which is *how do I update the image which is in my deployment when my image tag upgrades?*

**Enter Solution**

- When you compile and build a new image with latest version of code, **tag it** with an incremental unique version. This tag can be anything unique or build number, etc.
- Then push this tagged image to docker registry
- Once the image is uploaded, this is when you can use `kubectl` or kubernetes API to update the deployment with the latest container image.

  `kubectl set image deployment/my-deployment test-kube-deployment-container=samplekubernetes020/testimage:1 --record`
- The above set of steps generally take place in your CI pipeline, where you store the image version or the image: version in the environment variable itself.

---

**Update Post comment**

Since you are using Jenkins, you can get the current *build number* and *commit-id* and many other variables in Jenkinsfile itself as Jenkins injects these values at builds runtime. For me, this works. Just a reference.

```
environment { 
   NAME = "myapp"
   VERSION = "${env.BUILD_ID}-${env.GIT_COMMIT}"
   IMAGE = "${NAME}:${VERSION}"
}
stages {
    stage('Build') {
        steps {
            echo "Running ${VERSION} on ${env.JENKINS_URL}"
            git branch: "${BRANCH}",  .....
            echo "for brnach ${env.BRANCH_NAME}"
            sh "docker build -t ${NAME} ."
            sh "docker tag ${NAME}:latest ${IMAGE_REPO}/${NAME}:${VERSION}"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The image that I am building is not a manual image build process. Image build is happening in my pipeline job. I am using CI/CD way. Image automatically will build from Jenkinsfile. So in image build how I can use random build number ? That is my exact confusion as I mentioned in question. I hope that you understood what I am actually looking for.

Comment: ahh ok. So you can get the current build number and commit id and many other varibls in Jenkinsfile itself as Jenkins injects this at runtime. For me this works.

NAME = "myapp"
VERSION = "${env.BUILD_ID}-${env.GIT_COMMIT}"
IMAGE = ${NAME}:${VERSION}"

Comment: Yes I understood.This is the the one I was actually looking for . Perfect update. Let me try. Thank you for your response.

Comment: I tried with your updated answer. But using the version number , I am getting the problem with pulling the latest image in my CI/CD pipeline. I updated my experiment and edited the question. Can you please look on that sir ?

Comment: ok, so after tagging the version you are only pushing the latest image. What you can do is push the versioned image and use the same in deployment YAML.

push cmd - `sh "docker push ${IMAGE_REPO}/${NAME}:${VERSION}"`

And your deplyment yaml has ..  `spacestudymilletech010/spacestudykubernetes:12334`

Comment: Yes I understood. But I am defining the image in deployment YAML file , then I can't give like spacestudykubernetes:1234 by hard coding. Because it is triggering from the Jenkins pipeline job under CI/CD. Only thing manually I am doing here commiting to SVN repo.So dynamically how I can refer the build number in deployment YAML file?

Comment: use kubernetes API to update deployment.yml remotly. https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/api-overview/

Comment: Cuurently I am using `kubectl apply` command for my deployment.yaml. Instead of that do I need to use `kubectl set image` ?

Answer (score 1):

This Jenkins pipeline approach worked for me. 
I am using Jenkins build number as a tag for docker image, pushing to docker hub. Now applying yaml file to k8s cluster and then updating the image in deployment with same tag.

Sample pipeline script snippet is here,

```
stage('Build Docker Image'){
        sh 'docker build -t {dockerId}/{projectName}:${BUILD_NUMBER} .'
  }
  stage('Push Docker Image'){
        withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'DOKCER_HUB_PASSWORD', variable: 'DOKCER_HUB_PASSWORD')]) {
          sh "docker login -u {dockerId} -p ${DOKCER_HUB_PASSWORD}"
        }
        sh 'docker push {dockerId}/{projectName}:${BUILD_NUMBER}'
  }
  stage("Deploy To Kuberates Cluster"){
        sh 'kubectl apply -f {yaml file name}.yaml'
        sh 'kubectl set image deployments/{deploymentName} {container name given in deployment yaml file}={dockerId}/{projectName}:${BUILD_NUMBER}'
  }
```